# Send push notifications in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS6 app that works. Now what do I have to do in my app and on my server to set up push notification.

There are bits and pieces of answers to this question. But most of it is dated and I don't want set something up the old way just to find out it's been deprecated.

- http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-ios-push-notification-services-for-beginners/
- http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1541-how-to-send-a-push-notification-to-an-iphone-user/
- http://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Thank you

Comment: Anything from mid 2011 should still work. It's not an API that changes often.

Comment: This is a too general question. I suggest you start by reading the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) as well as this [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently set up push on an app I was working on and followed these tutorials :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

These are well written and they work.

Comment: These are great -- and I see that they are working in iOS6 perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very helpful mac application. I use this to simulate push notification without server : https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher